# Comparing files and creating notepad to tell which line is different in php

Tags: php

I was stuck for sometime after this some sort of code. I'm not so new yet not so old in coding using php but I need help with regards to this one.

I have two directories which has more than 1 file, it may come as text or xml.
Lets say directory 1 is populated today and directory 2 will be populated tom.Both directories have the same number of files and the same name and order.

What I want to have is a comparing tool which will comapre each and every file but of course i need to compare those with similar names and then if there's a difference or update in either of the file, it will create a notepad which will write the filename, line in which they have difference.

I came up to this part but im stuck and i need your help guys.

Thanks.

```
<?php
$dirA = glob('C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs1\*');
$dirB = glob('C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs2\*');

//Checking that the files are the same

foreach($dirA as $fileName) {
    // the file exists in the other folder as well with the same name
    if ($exists = array_search($fileName, $dirB) !== false) {
       // it exists!
    if (md5_file($fileName) !== md5_file($dirB[$exists])) {
        // The files are not identical so i need to create a text file to show what line is not the same
        copy($fileName, $dirB[$exists]);
        /* problem here is you didn't specify which in your requirements */
    }
} else {
    // it doesn't (what to do here? you didn't specify!)
}
}

// compare the other way
foreach($dirB as $fileName) {
// does the file exist in the other directory?
if ($exists = array_search($fileName, $dirA) !== false) {
    // it exists!
    if (md5_file($fileName) !== md5_file($dirA[$exists])) {
        copy($fileName, $dirA[$exists]);
    }
} else {
    // it doesn't (what to do here? you didn't specify!)
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get a list of all files in each directory

You can use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) to grab a list of files in each directory...

```
$dirA = glob('C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs1\*');
$dirB = glob('C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs2\*');
```

### Checking that the files are the same

You can do a simple md5 checksum on matching filenames to determine if they are identical or not.

```
foreach($dirA as $fileName) {
    // does the file exist in the other directory?
    if ($exists = array_search($fileName, $dirB) !== false) {
        // it exists!
        if (md5_file($fileName) !== md5_file($dirB[$exists])) {
            // The files aren't identical so one of them needs updated
            copy($fileName, $dirB[$exists]);
            /* problem here is you didn't specify which in your requirements */
        }
    } else {
        // it doesn't (what to do here? you didn't specify!)
    }
}

// compare the other way
foreach($dirB as $fileName) {
    // does the file exist in the other directory?
    if ($exists = array_search($fileName, $dirA) !== false) {
        // it exists!
        if (md5_file($fileName) !== md5_file($dirA[$exists])) {
            copy($fileName, $dirA[$exists]);
        }
    } else {
        // it doesn't (what to do here? you didn't specify!)
    }
}
```

### Update files

There's one part of your requirements that you have not clearly defined behavior in... Which file do you update? Because while a change may have been made to `C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs1\test1.txt` these requirements do not distinguish between you overwriting `C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs1\test1.txt` with `C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs2\test1.txt` or `C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs2\test1.txt` with `C:\Users\aganda88\Desktop\testing docs\testingdocs1\test1.txt`... i.e. the fact that the files are not the same doesn't specify which one should be the **source** and which one should be the **destination**. Without that it doesn't really matter if you know that they aren't the same or not...

Comment: ill handle the else, since i have something for the else if in case it routes to else